# How I can contribute to the open source work of localization of Android OS for specific language

Tags: languages, localization, aosp

As Android is the open source, the translation of the localization for all languages should be the work on the same principle. How can I contribute to the translation of system messages and the user interface for some specific language?

Comment: Android is OpenSource, yes, however as Google is the one who controls what is included into the next release. See https://source.android.com/setup/contribute Note that contributing requires creating a full fledged AOSP development environment which requires a Linux system, dozens of downloaded GB, hundred of GB on the hard disk and several hours to set-up and build.

Comment: Thank you Robert, so there is no more direct way for the language translation contribution?

Comment: From Google perspective any contribution is equal, just changing one line requires the whole process.